# How to Build Entity Framework Project using Npanday

Tags: maven, entity-framework-4

I am using Npnday 1.5. I have tried to build my project using Npanday. But DLL generated using Npanday has some issue. Because When I replace that DLL with other DLL which is generated by Visual Studio 2010, then my web application runs perfectly.

Have any one buid Entity Framework Project using Napanday??

Please tell me What are the steps required to build an entity framework project using Npanday.
Mainly what changes are required to do in POM.xml file???